# iOS: didStartMonitoringForRegion not called

Tags: ios

I am running this off my iPhone 4 device.

First, here is the relevant code:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    CLLocationDegrees latitude = 45.50568;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude = -73.21352;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    CLLocationDistance radius = 200.0;

    CLRegion *myRegion = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:center radius:radius identifier:@"region1"];

    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:myRegion];
}
```

But at no point whatsoever does `didStartMonitoringForRegion` get called, not even `monitoringDidFailForRegion` gets called.

What am I doing wrong? My device supports regional monitoring, I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: is locationManager initialised?

Comment: I'm an idiot!! Thanks. Working overtime can really get to you I guess.